# Feature issue when simplifying and optimizing code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I recently wrote a code to change the mode from light to dark and decided to simplify it to make it more efficient, optimal and shorter but I ran into a problem because I don't want to set the **"theme"** and **"current-theme"** attributes.
I checked the jQuery docs, just like the logs in the console, I even tried to use **data** and nothing. If someone would help me simplify this code, I would be grateful or help me solve the problem with unchanging attributes, I would be grateful :)

Full Code:

```
;(function($){'use strict';
setMode();
$('#theme-mode, #theme-mode i').on('click', function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('theme-dark');
});
$('#theme-mode, #theme-mode i').click(function(){
    switchMode();
});
function switchMode(){
    if($('body').hasClass('theme-dark')){
        $('#theme-mode i').removeClass('dd-sun').addClass('fa-moon');
        $('body').removeClass('theme-light');
        $.cookie("theme_mode", "dark", {expires: 365, secure: true});
    }else{
        $('#theme-mode i').removeClass('fa-moon').addClass('dd-sun');
        $('body').addClass('theme-light').removeClass('theme-dark');
        $.cookie("theme_mode", "light", {expires: 365, secure: true});
    }
    setMode();
}
function setMode(){
    if(checkMode('theme_mode')=="dark"){
        $('body').addClass('theme-dark');
        $('#theme-style').attr('href', 'css/theme-dark.css');
        $('#theme-mode i').removeClass('dd-sun').addClass('fa-moon');
    }else{
        $('body').addClass('theme-light');
        $('#theme-style').attr('href', 'css/theme-light.css');
        $('#theme-mode i').removeClass('fa-moon').addClass('dd-sun');
    }
}
function checkMode(){
    var cookieMode = $.cookie("theme_mode");
    if(cookieMode != ""){
        if(cookieMode=="dark"){
            $.cookie("theme_mode", "dark", {expires: 365, secure: true});
        }else{
            $.cookie("theme_mode", "light", {expires: 365, secure: true});
        }
    }
    return cookieMode;
}
})(jQuery);
```

Shorted Code:

```
;(function($){'use strict';
$("#theme-mode").click(function(){
    var e=$(this).attr("data-theme"),c=$(this).attr("data-current-theme");
    console.log(e+c);
    $('body').addClass('theme-'+e);
    $("#theme-mode").attr("data-theme",e);
    //$("#theme-mode").attr("current-theme",c);
    $.cookie("theme_mode",e,{expires:365, secure: true});
    $("#theme-style").attr("href", "css/theme/"+e+".css");
    if($('body').hasClass('theme-dark')){
        $('#theme-mode i').removeClass('dd-sun').addClass('fa-moon');
        $('body').removeClass('theme-light');
        //$.cookie("theme_mode", "dark", {expires: 365, secure: true});
    }else{
        $('#theme-mode i').removeClass('fa-moon').addClass('dd-sun');
        $('body').addClass('theme-light').removeClass('theme-dark');
        //$.cookie("theme_mode", "light", {expires: 365, secure: true});
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bad idea to put all in one block. So is in your shorted code no initial setMode() and no cookie query. This is my shorted version:

```
;(function($){'use strict';
function setLightMode(){
    $('#theme-style').attr('href', 'css/theme-light.css');
    $('body').removeClass('theme-dark').addClass('theme-light');
    $('#theme-mode i').removeClass('fa-moon').addClass('dd-sun');   
    $.cookie("theme_mode", "light", {expires: 365, secure: true});
}
function setDarkMode(){
    $('#theme-style').attr('href', 'css/theme-dark.css');
    $('body').removeClass('theme-light').addClass('theme-dark');
    $('#theme-mode i').removeClass('dd-sun').addClass('fa-moon');
    $.cookie("theme_mode", "dark", {expires: 365, secure: true});
}
function checkMode(){
    var cookieMode = $.cookie("theme_mode");
    if(cookieMode=="dark"){ setDarkMode(); }
    else{ setLightMode(); }
}
checkMode();
$('#theme-mode, #theme-mode i').click(function(){
    if( $('body').hasClass('theme-light') ){ setDarkMode(); }
    else{ setLightMode(); }
});
})(jQuery);
```

If you don't want setMode() and the cookie query anymore, than you can do it without the functions:

```
;(function($){'use strict';
$('#theme-mode, #theme-mode i').click(function(){
    if( $('body').hasClass('theme-light') ){ 
        $('#theme-style').attr('href', 'css/theme-dark.css');
        $('body').removeClass('theme-light').addClass('theme-dark');
        $('#theme-mode i').removeClass('dd-sun').addClass('fa-moon');
    }
    else{ 
        $('#theme-style').attr('href', 'css/theme-light.css');
        $('body').removeClass('theme-dark').addClass('theme-light');
        $('#theme-mode i').removeClass('fa-moon').addClass('dd-sun');   
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

If you still want it shorter, you must reduce the if-else blocks to just changing the stylesheets and toggle the body class after that. But then you must instead redefine your theme-css files.

```
;(function($){'use strict';
$('#theme-mode, #theme-mode i').click(function(){
    if( $('body').hasClass('theme-light') ){ 
        $('#theme-style').attr('href', 'css/theme-dark.css');
    }
    else{ 
        $('#theme-style').attr('href', 'css/theme-light.css');
    }
    $('body').toggleClass('theme-light');
});
})(jQuery);
```

And when thats not enough, the only possibility i see, is to reduce the whitespace:

```
;(function($){'use strict';
$('#theme-mode, #theme-mode i').click(function(){
    if( $('body').hasClass('theme-light') ){ $('#theme-style').attr('href', 'css/theme-dark.css'); }
    else{ $('#theme-style').attr('href', 'css/theme-light.css'); }
    $('body').toggleClass('theme-light');
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Only, without checking the cookies, it will not set the style selected by the user

Comment: Because it's supposed to work like this
1. Checks if the style selected by the user is saved, if not then sets the default to light and if it is to the one selected by the user.
2. After clicking on the button, the icon changes style

Comment: And I want to make this code as short as possible and work as it should

Comment: And I would prefer to have 1 max functions 2 and not 3, so that there is as little code as possible

Comment: I processed what you sent but it does not work and it does not show errors https://pastebin.com/irMmFYw9

Comment: Okay, I fixed the works. Can't you shorten it any more?

Comment: @Kondzio when it helped you then please mark the question as accepted